# Azure Build Pipelines: reference predefined variable from expression

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, yaml

I'd like to use the value of a [predefined variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) from an expression in an **Azure** build pipeline.

It folows the **YML** definition:

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- script: echo ${{ format('{0}-vars', variables['Build.Repository.Name']) }} # outcome: -vars
- script: echo ${{ format('{0}-vars', 'a_string') }} # outcome: a_string-vars
```

I'm still not an expert of this environment, but it's pretty clear to me that `variables['Build.Repository.Name']` is not resolved. Outside an expression using `$(Build.Repository.Name)` *perfectly works*.

What's the right way to reference a **predefined variable** inside an **expression**? (I wasn't able to find it in docs).

Any help really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops) so you can get more information about the variables available and the syntax of expressions. But, to summarize, in terms of using variables in expressions, you have two ways:

- Index syntax: variables['MyVar']
- Property dereference syntax: variables.MyVar

Comment: Thank you for replying, I know that document. I've already tryied with `variables.Build.Repository.Name` but it's still not resolved. The problem here is that I want to access a **predefined variable** in an **expression**. Maybe it is not possible....

Comment: In the article that I shared above, you have examples how to use variables on your expressions, but the important detail, as referenced on the documentation, is:   "Depending on the execution context, different variables are available.

If you create pipelines using YAML, then pipeline variables are available.
If you create build pipelines using classic editor, then build variables are available.
If you create release pipelines using classic editor, then release variables are available."

Comment: so, since you are creating pipelines using YAML, then you have the pipeline variables available - Follows the list of the variables you have available. - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: So, according to the documentation, if you want to have the build variables available, you need to use the classic editor to create your build pipeline. That's at least my assumption.

Comment: But most importantly, this was your question "What's the right way to reference a predefined variable inside an expression? (I wasn't able to find it in docs).". And I gave you the answer for your question. Now, we are moving to a different question, so "Which predefined variables are available on my build pipeline and my context?".

Comment: I'm not sure that the comments here are correct. In the "Depending on the execution context..." part of the documentation, both its "pipeline variables" and "build variables" links go to the same page (the one linked by Hugo above). However, on that page the "Pipeline variables" section only has one variable in it - `Pipeline.Workspace`. It's difficult to believe that when you're not using the classic editor, you only get access to one variable. Also, I am using Build variables in my YAML ok - although there is this bug: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/issues/436

Comment: @AdamGoodwin you can use all the variables mentioned on the link I shared, including the Build variables, since al those are predefined variables. Also, follows here the list of release variables, in case you want to use them during your release - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables

Answer (score 2):

I could be conflating two different meanings of "template" as used in Azure DevOps, but I think the issue is the syntax you're using for your expression. When you do the following:

```
${{ format('{0}-vars', variables['Build.Repository.Name']) }}
```

You are using [template expression syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#template-expression-syntax) (i.e. the `${{variable}}` syntax).

That's fine, but I think the "Available in templates?" column in [this table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables) is your problem. For the `Build.Repository.Name` variable it says "No".

Again, I could be mistaken, but I take that to mean that the variable – for whatever reason – cannot be used with that expression syntax.

I think if you use [runtime expression syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#runtime-expression-syntax), you will get the behaviour you want.

i.e. this:

```
$[format('{0}-vars', variables['Build.Repository.Name'])]
```

This has been working for me in a pipeline I'm working on.

Be careful though, it seems like there is a [bug](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/issues/436) where if you use the [property dereference syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#variables) (i.e. `variables.Build.Repository.Name`) you will get the same symptoms as your current problem. This was happening to me as well.

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do as per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops) would be using

```
 repository: $(Build.Repository.Name)
```

However whenever you have conditions check, you could use,

```
condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.Repository.Name'], 'Sample'))
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I need it in expressions. I want to add a string when setting a variable group name.